# Existence of circuit passing through each vertex in a directed graph

Tags: graph-theory

Are there necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of a circuit, or a disjoint set of circuits, that passes through each vertex once in a directed graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the classic text, "Computers and Intractability, A Guide to the Theory of NP-Completeness" by Garey and Johnson, the following problem:

**Partition into Hamiltonian Subgraphs**

> Given a directed graph $G=(V,A)$, can
>   the vertices be partitioned into
>   disjoint sets $V_1, V_2, \dots, V_k$
>   for some $k$, such that each $V_i$
>   contains at least three vertices and
>   induces a subgraph of $G$ that
>   contains a Hamiltonian Circuit.

is NP-Complete, by a reduction from 3SAT.

The book also mentions that if we allow each $V_i$ to contain at least *two* vertices, then this is solvable in polynomial time using Matching techniques.

Answer (score 2):

A collection of disjoint cycles that cover all vertices of an (undirected) graph is known as a 2-factor. [This paper](http://www.is.kochi-u.ac.jp/~fujisawa/papers/08AFS.pdf) references some criterion of Tutte for the existence of these, which, paraphrasing the authors, in some sense completely solves the problem. It's Theorem 1 on page 2, which points to "The factors of graphs" by Tutte (1952).

Comment: Isn't a 2-factorization about the edges of a graph and not the vertices?

Comment: 2-factorization is partitioning of the (edges of the) graph into 2-factors.

Comment: You are correct, I didn't read your answer properly. Is this (existence of 2-factor) valid for directed graphs too?

Comment: In general, k-factors only make sense for undirected graphs (unless $k=2$), so probably not, but it's best to consult Tutte's paper.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any are known. A quick search on the web gave [a paper by Gutin and Yeo](http://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/23/ocr-ajc-v23-p115.pdf), which also directs to Chapter 1 of **Digraphs - Theory, Algorithms, and Applications** by Bang-Jensen and Gutin (Springer Monographs, ISBN: 978-1-84800-997-4).

In any case, if there were necessary and sufficient conditions, then taking any graph and replacing each edge by a pair of directed edges going back-and-forth would give you a characterization of Hamiltonian graphs, if I'm not very confused, which is not known.